# How to downgrade angular cli from 1.0.1 to 1.0.0

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

Hi I am having touble deploying my app because of version of angular-cli.

I checked and the version of my angular-cli is

```
@angular/common: 2.4.10
@angular/compiler: 2.4.10
@angular/core: 2.4.10
@angular/forms: 2.4.10
@angular/http: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.10
@angular/router: 3.4.10
@angular/cli: 1.0.1  <-- 1.0.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.10
```

I really need to downgrade the version to 1.0.0 beta-24 version.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean  
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.0.0-beta.24
```

Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands to completely remove the angular-cli and install it with the desired version afterwards

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean  
npm install -g angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.24
```